# Assumed size arrays: Colon vs. asterisk - DIMENSION(:) arr vs. arr(*)

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90

Is there any difference between these two methods of declaring an assumed-size array?

e.g.

```
real, dimension(:) :: arr
```

and

```
real               :: arr(*)
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The form

```
real, dimension(:) :: arr
```

declares an *assumed-shape* array, while the form

```
real :: arr(*)
```

declares an *assumed-size* array.

And, yes, there are differences between their use.  The differences arise because, approximately, the compiler 'knows' the shape of the assumed-shape array but not of the assumed-size array.  The extra information available to the compiler means that, among other things, assumed-shape arrays can be used in whole-array expressions.  An assumed-size array can only be used in whole array expressions when it's an actual argument in a procedure reference that does not require the array's shape.  Oh, and also in a call to the intrinsic `lbound` -- but not in a call to the intrinsic `ubound`.  There are other subtle, and not-so-subtle, differences which your close reading of the standard or of a good Fortran book will reveal.

Some advice for new Fortran programmers is to use assumed-shape arrays when possible. They were not available before Fortran 90, so you will see lots of assumed-size arrays in old code. Assumed-shape arrays are better in new code, because the `shape` and `size` functions can be used to query their sizes to avoid out-of-bounds error and to `allocate` arrays whose dimensions depend on the dimensions of input arrays.

Comment: it should be noted the modern assumed shape `(:)` form requires an explicit interface. If you are working on old code with external subroutines you must use the `*` or provide the interface.

Comment: @agentp: For the sake of coding explicitly, it's better to provide the interface rather than the `*` whenever possible. Better yet, stick the routine in a module if appropriate, as interfaces aren't needed when modules are used.

Comment: Side note: assumed size arrays are interoperable, but assumed shape arrays are not.  That's one reason that you might still need to use assumed size arrays in new code.

Answer (score 19):

[High Performance Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24545407/3157076) explains the difference between the two statements - in short: yes, there's a difference; only one declares an assumed-size array - and the implications.

However, as `dimension(:)` but is mentioned, seemingly against not `dimension(*)`, I'll add one thing.

```
real, dimension(:) :: arr1
real, dimension(*) :: arr2
```

is equivalent to

```
real :: arr1(:)
real :: arr2(*)
```

or even using `dimension` statements.  [I don't want to encourage that, so I won't write out the example.]

The important difference in the question is the use of `*` and `:`, not `dimension`.

Perhaps there was some conflation of *assumed-size* with *dummy argument*?  It is as a dummy argument where this choice is most common.