# Is there any reason to use an assumed-size array if the array rank/size are available?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, fortran, fortran90

If I know the rank and/or size of an array being passed to a function or subroutine, is there any reason to use an assumed-shape or assumed-size array? For example, if I can replace

```
function f(a,m,n)
   real,dimension(*),intent(inout) :: a
   ! ...
end function
```

with

```
function f(a,m,n)
    real,dimension(m,n),intent(inout) :: a
    ! ...
end function
```

is there any reason (in Fortran 90 or later) to not do so?

Comment: Your code example has an assumed-size array argument.  The title and text mention assumed-shape also.  Assumed shape and assumed size are _massively_ different in terms of implications.  Are you truly interested in comparing explicit-shape with assumed-shape?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I am indeed interested in comparing assumed-size with explicit-shape (if that's what you mean by the second example above). I will update the title.

Answer (score 5):

Too long for a comment, not much of an answer ...

This

```
function f(a,m,n)
    real,dimension(m,n),intent(inout) :: a
    ! ...
end function
```

does not make `a` an assumed-shape array, it has explicit shape `(m,n)`.  These days I write

```
function f(a)
    real,dimension(:,:),intent(inout) :: a
    ! ...
end function
```

In this version `a` is definitely assumed-shape.  On the (increasingly) rare occasions I need the size or shape of an array inside a procedure I get it by writing `shape(a)` or suchlike.

Finally, to answer OP's question, refer to [Assumed size arrays: Colon vs. asterisk - DIMENSION(:) arr vs. arr(*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543329/assumed-size-arrays-colon-vs-asterisk-dimension-arr-vs-arr)

Comment: Pretty much when you start to make functions f2, f3, and f4 and they are only differing by the size of M and N, then you head towards @High Performance Mark example #2. Mark mentioned SHAPE and UBOUND and LBOUND become useful.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I wrote assumed-shape when I meant assumed-size.