# How to pass static arrays to functions that accept allocatable arrays without passing the length of the array

Tags: fortran

I programmed a Knuth shuffle in Fortran as follows

```
subroutine knuth_shuffle(array, length)
    implicit none

    integer :: length
    integer :: array(length)

    integer :: randomIndex
    integer :: temp

    do i = 1, length - 2
        randomIndex = floor(randomBetween(real(i), real(length)))
        temp = array(i)
        array(i) = array(randomIndex)
        array(randomIndex) = temp
    enddo
end subroutine knuth_shuffle
```

Every time I call the subroutine I have to enter the array length too.

```
call knuth_shuffle(A, size(A))
```

Is there a way I can change the subroutine so when I call it, it looks more like:

```
call knuth_shuffle(A)
```

Comment: @Yossarian, please don't do mass editing to remove tags without also looking at the post contents which may be amenable to improvements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change

```
subroutine knuth_shuffle(array, length)
    implicit none

    integer :: length
    integer :: array(length)

    integer :: randomIndex
    integer :: temp
```

to

```
subroutine knuth_shuffle(array)
    implicit none

    integer :: array(:)

    integer :: length
    integer :: randomIndex
    integer :: temp

    length = size(array)
```

or you could just chuck away the local variable `length` and write

```
subroutine knuth_shuffle(array)
    implicit none

    integer :: array(:)

    integer :: randomIndex
    integer :: temp
    integer :: i

    do i = 1, size(array) - 2
        randomIndex = floor(randomBetween(real(i), real(size(array))))
        temp = array(i)
        array(i) = array(randomIndex)
        array(randomIndex) = temp
    enddo
end subroutine knuth_shuffle
```

While I'm answering: the subroutine doesn't know or care if the actual argument supplied as `array` is allocatable or static.  There is nothing in the subroutine that is affected by, nor which affects, the allocation status of the array.  From the subroutine's perspective `array` is of *assumed-shape*, on which point see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543329/assumed-size-arrays-colon-vs-asterisk-dimension-arr-vs-arr).

As @francescalus has commented, if it has *assumed-shape* array arguments the procedure requires an *explicit interface*   The easy way to provide that is to have the compiler generate the interface; either (preferable) put the procedure in a `module` and `use` it or (more limited applicability) include it within the `contains` section of another program unit (maybe the main program unit).  A last resort, generally only to be taken when modifying old code, would be to write an `interface` block yourself.