# Passing array in Fortran: difference between `DIMENSION(:)` and `DIMENSION X(*)`

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran77, intel-fortran

I came across a rather peculiar behavior when was passing arrays to `LSODA` procedure of `ODEPACK` library.

The scene: Intel Fortran compiler, one of the recent ones, OS Windows. I have a project that uses features of Fortran 2003, but dirty computational work is passed to `LSODA`, which is Fortran 77.

`LSODA` is declared as

```
  SUBROUTINE DLSODA (F, NEQ, Y, T, TOUT, ITOL, RTOL, ATOL, ITASK,
 1            ISTATE, IOPT, RWORK, LRW, IWORK, LIW, JAC, JT)
  EXTERNAL F, JAC
  INTEGER NEQ, ITOL, ITASK, ISTATE, IOPT, LRW, IWORK, LIW, JT
  DOUBLE PRECISION Y, T, TOUT, RTOL, ATOL, RWORK
  DIMENSION NEQ(*), Y(*), RTOL(*), ATOL(*), RWORK(LRW), IWORK(LIW)
```

note the arrays. To call all that I do:

```
CALL DLSODA(FDARCY, NEQ, SATCCUR, TCUR, TNEXT, ITOL, RTOL, ATOL, ITASK, &
            ISTATE, IOPT, RWORK, LRW, IWORK, LIW, JDUM, JT)
```

Let's focus on `SATCCUR` (in `Y` position of `LSODA`). It is declared:

```
REAL(8), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: SATCCUR
```

Just in case, in the debugger I checked that `DOUBLE PRECISION` is `REAL(8)`. At some point `SATCCUR` is also allocated. The problem is, that `LSODA` with this call sees complete garbage. The pointer `Y` sometimes points to something that I cannot either read or write, leading to the program crash. The only way to fix the problem was to change the call to:

```
CALL DLSODA(FDARCY, NEQ, SATCCUR(1), TCUR, TNEXT, ITOL, RTOL, ATOL, ITASK, &
            ISTATE, IOPT, RWORK(1), LRW, IWORK(1), LIW, JDUM, JT)
```

Notice that I am not passing the array, but its first element --- the pass by reference of Fortran helps here, as `LSODA` would effectively get the address of the first element. And I had to do it with all arrays in the call.

If I use the example that is supplied by the `LSODA`'s documentation, everything works fine with passing whole arrays. The differences that I could spot:

- The arrays in `LSODA`'s example are statically allocated, whereas I do dynamic allocation.
- In place of function `F` I pass the function internal to the subroutine. It makes my life much easier, as it captures parameters necessary to run it. This, I believe, is Fortran 2003 feature. But I can't see how this can create the problem as the problem occurs much earlier than `F` call.

So, the question is why does this happen? Is it an expected behavior?

PS. Also, for `LSODA` to compile I had to switch off the function interface check as it's internally passing `DOUBLE PRECISION` array where `INTEGER` array is expected --- shameless hack on the authors side!

### UPDATE

I've managed to trace down the error. The problem was that in my interface declaration for `DLSODA` I have put

```
INTERFACE
    SUBROUTINE DLSODA(F, NEQ, Y, T, TOUT, ITOL, RTOL, ATOL, ITASK, &
        ISTATE, IOPT, RWORK, LRW, IWORK, LIW, JAC, JT)
    USE GENERAL
    EXTERNAL :: F, JAC
    INTEGER :: NEQ, ITOL, ITASK, ISTATE, IOPT, LRW, LIW, JT, IWORK
    REAL(DP) :: T, TOUT, RTOL, ATOL, RWORK
    DIMENSION RWORK(LRW), IWORK(LIW)
    REAL(DP), DIMENSION(:) :: Y
    END SUBROUTINE DLSODA
END INTERFACE
```

Note the declaration for `Y` and how it is different from `RWORK`. Apparently, there is a difference between

```
REAL(8), DIMENSION(:) :: X
```

and

```
REAL(8) X
DIMENSION X(*)
```

I thought this was just a matter of style. Can someone explain why there is a difference?

Comment: @francescalus was writing such a long post, forgot the question! So, is there a reason why this happens? Is it expected that garbage would be passed if I am passing an allocated array? Is it a part of the standard?

Comment: @francescalus I've edited the question.

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong having an (allocated) allocatable array as an actual argument to an assumed-size dummy argument; there is nothing inherently wrong (in modern Fortran) with having an internal procedure as an actual argument.  That is, your problem could well be elsewhere, and memory issues can manifest in strange ways.  We probably can'thelp much more unless you can reduce your program to a complete (and minimal) test case (such as shown in [mcve]).

Comment: @francescalus OK, I thought I might have been mssing something in Fortran specs regarding passing arrays. I will try to get the problem smaller, so I can post it here. Yet, it's so strange: even with a debugger I can see how garbage appears on LSODA sight, yet on a caller side it's all fine.

Comment: @francescalus I've found the source of the error, any ideas why there is a difference between `DIMENSION(:)` and `DIMENSION X(*)` declarations?

Comment: There's a massive difference between `a(:)` and `a(*)`.  Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24543329/3157076) cover it for You?

Comment: @francescalus Yes, thanks! My understanding is that with `DIMENSION(:)` declaration compiler passes extra information regarding array size, perhaps, appended in the front. So, what reaches the procedure is not the pointer to the first array element, and thus I was getting a garbage.