# Passing an array of unknown length to a fortran subroutine from C fails

Tags: c, fortran

I have a fortran subroutine that takes two arrays and prints their contents

```
subroutine my_subroutine(a, b) bind(c, name='my_subroutine')
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    integer(c_int) a(:)
    real(c_double) b(:)

    print *, "Printing from Fortran subroutine:"
    print *, a(1)
    print *, b(1)

end subroutine my_subroutine
```

and a C main file

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void my_subroutine(int *, double *);

int main()
{
    int *a = calloc(5, sizeof(int));
    double *b = calloc(5, sizeof(double));

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        a[i] = i;
        b[i] = i;
    }

    my_subroutine(a, b);

    free(a);
    free(b);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The fortran routine fails at the line `print *, a`. If I change two lines of the subroutine to

```
integer(c_int) a(5)
real(c_double) b(5)
```

it prints without issue. Is there a way to pass these arrays to the subroutine without specifying their length?

Comment: Relevant: [Assumed size arrays: Colon vs. asterisk - DIMENSION(:) arr vs. arr(*)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24543329/2402272)

Comment: @JohnBollinger when I changed ```a(:)``` to ```a(*)```, it works!